# Failed to validate if SLR: AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I was following the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html

I have created IAM user with permissions like PassRole, CreteNodeGroup etc; created node roles, cluster roles and was able to access it using

```
kubectl get svc
```

Then I followed the guide further and wanted to create a node group. I selected all the options I need and pressed `Create`.

However I got the error

```
Failed to validate if SLR: AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup already exists due to missing permissions for 'iam:GetRole'
```

In my IAM related permission group I have permissions like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/eksKubBegEKSClusterRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/eksKubBegEKSNodeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:GetRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/eksKubBegEKSNodeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor5",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:GetRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/eksKubBegEKSClusterRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a group of EKS related permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:ListUpdates",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:*:000000000000:cluster/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:DeleteCluster",
                "eks:DescribeNodegroup",
                "eks:ListNodegroups",
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:GetFederationToken",
                "eks:DeleteNodegroup",
                "eks:DescribeCluster",
                "eks:CreateNodegroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:eks:*:000000000000:nodegroup/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:eks:*:000000000000:cluster/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:GetSessionToken",
                "sts:GetAccessKeyInfo",
                "eks:ListClusters",
                "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
                "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
                "eks:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But what exactly am I missing?

Comment: I was able to create the nodegroup using my root user for that instance. But I am not sure if I will have issues with my IAM user regarding the access in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I just went through the same thing after attempting to refactor my terraform code. EKS backplane provisioned fine. Got this same error as the nodegroup provisioning began. Turns out it had nothing to do with my code. The service-linked role (AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup) did not exist. Go to IAM in the console, **Create Role**, select **EKS**, select **EKS-Nodegroup** as your use case and follow the remaining prompts to create the role.

After I did that my code ran fine.

Comment: Worked for me as well... How did you figure this out?